# How to create a draggable element with HammerJs and Angular

Tags: angular, gesture, hammer.js

I am trying to implement a draggable functionality with HammerJs and Angular but my element does not move. The mouse points are printed out but the element does not move.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  styles: ['.demo-one {width:200px;height:200px;background-color: slateblue;color: #fff;}',
           '.demo-one:hover {cursor:pointer}'],
  template: `<div class="demo-one" [style.marginleft.px]="x" [style.margintop.px]="y"
  (panstart)="onPanStart($event)" (panmove)="onPan($event)">
    <div class="label">{{title}}</div>
    <div class="location">({{x}}, {{y}})</div>
  </div>`
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  title = 'Drag Me!';

  startX = 0;
  startY = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onPanStart(event: any): void {
    this.startX = this.x;
    this.startY = this.y;
  }

  onPan(event: any): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.x = this.startX + event.deltaX;
    this.y = this.startY + event.deltaY;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `position: absolute` for the draggable element and set its `left` and `top` instead of `marginleft` and `margintop` when dragging it. By doing that, the element will be moved more freely.

Check the following:

```
styles: ['.demo-one {position: absolute; width:200px;height:200px;background-color: slateblue;color: #fff;}','.demo-one:hover {cursor:pointer}']

template: `<div class="demo-one" [style.left]="x" [style.top]="y (panstart)="onPanStart($event)" (panmove)="onPan($event)">
```

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: How to move using Arrow buttons? right now it is moving using mouse Cursor.

Comment: or even css `transform: translation(...)`